# Disable swap file on flie type

Tags: vim

In my vimrc file I currently have this:

```
set directory=~/.vim/.swp//
```

Although, this is a problem for my home disk when I open up large log files. Is there a way to disable swap files for a particular file extension? I am thinking somewhere in my vimrc file there would be something to this effect:

```
if filename == *.log
    no log
else
    set directory=~/.vim/.swp//
```

Comment: you can open a file without the swap file using `vim -n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the command below in your `.vimrc` file

```
autocmd BufEnter *.log :set noswapfile
```

or you can open any file by using the option `-n`

```
vim -n file.log
```